# How to delete pointer from a dynamic array of pointers at an exact index?

Tags: c++, c++14

When we have dynamic array of pointers in hand, suppose we want to delete 3rd index of this array and copying the higher pointers down one slot.

Q1: Do we need to delete 3rd element?

Q2: What happens after  we make delete aPtr[3] and assigning new pointer to aPtr[3]

Does the code part do what I am trying to do?

'''

```
A **aPtr = new A*[10];

for(int i=0; i< 10; i++)
{
    aPtr[i] = new A;
}

delete aPtr[3];

for(int i=3; i<9; i++)
{
    aPtr[i] = aPtr[i+1];
}
```

'''

Another question regardless of the previous one. When we want to delete all the elements in the array of pointers, is the statement "delete [] aPtr;" also required?

'''

```
A **aPtr = new A*[10];

for(int i=0; i< 10; i++)
{
    aPtr[i] = new A;
}


for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    delete aPtr[i];
}

delete[] aPtr; //<-----Is this line required to free the memory?
```

'''

Comment: We would use `std::vector` instead, which does all of this for us.

Comment: I cannot use std::vector because of working on a school assignment :(

Comment: For every `new` there must be exactly one `delete` and for every `new[]` there must be exactly one `delete[]`. So Q1 and last question: yes. For Q2: `aPtr[3]` will point to the object that the pointer you assigned it points to.

Comment: *I cannot use std::vector because of working on a school assignment :(* -- When are these schools going to allow usage of `std::vector`?  It's been part of C++ for officially **24 years** now.  Also, writing programs using `new[]` and `delete[]`, at least for most programs, is now discouraged in this day and age of C++.

Comment: After removing one pointer and shifting the other pointers down by 1, your last two indices will contain the same pointer, which you may only delete once at the end of the program, which is difficult to achieve. I would set the pointer at index `9` to `nullptr` after the shifting for loop. - BTW Even using `new` and `delete` is discouraged except for special cases. `make_unique` is the better alternative.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I half agree with you. On the other hand, you should walk before you run. Knowing how to use raw pointers directly is part of C++, and teaching it is important.

Comment: @JosephLarson -- I've seen too many C++ school assignments where they ask the student to do a difficult project (design a parking lot, menu system, hotel reservation, whatever), and for some oddball reason, told they cannot use `std::vector`, as if the program will just magically write itself if vectors (or any other container) are used.  This is where I totally disagree with the "no vector" requirements.  All those requirements wind up doing is making the student drop C++ and go to another language, such as Python or C#.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Oh -- I largely agree with you. However, based on the questions we see in Stack Overflow about it, I'd say the people being given the assignments still don't get the basics. I don't like teaching container classes until they can handle doing it themselves first. But I can see how others would feel differently.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks good with one exception.

```
delete aPtr[3];

for(int i=3; i<9; i++)
{
    aPtr[i] = aPtr[i+1];
}
```

Add this:

```
aPtr[9] = nullptr;
```

Otherwise aPtr[8] and aPtr[9] both point to the same place, and later when you delete the whole thing, you'll double-delete that pointer.

Otherwise, it looks good.